# Dual GPU Dual Display setup: monitor is black but detected

Tags: xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor, gpu

I've recently installed linux alognside Windows 10 and I'm trying to use a second monitor the way I use it on Windows.
The first monitor is connected to a GTX 770 and the second one to the iGPU.
I've set up an xorg.conf file to use both monitors, but only the first one is usable. The second one is black (it's somewhat working because I can move my mouse on it and see the pointer, but I can't drag windows on it.
Also, when I run `xrandr --query` or `xrandr --listmonitors` I only see the first screen (HDMI-0): the second monitor (HDMI1) isn't even detected apparently.
But when I run `xrandr --screen 1` it shows the second screen (HDMI1) just fine: connected, working, the resolution is automatically assigned (even correctly), ...
The problem is that I can't find a way to make it usable.
Any suggestions?
Note: I'm using the nvidia drivers

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 375.66  (build-user@build-machine)  Mon Aug 21 18:17:00 UTC 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "off"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Philips"
    ModelName      "Philips 239CQH"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    HorizSync      30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh    56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 770"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    VendorName     "Intel Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    Option         "TwinView" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth   24
    Option         "TwinView" "off"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

xrandr --screen 0

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

xrandr --screen 1

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 430mm x 270mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```